# AMCharts category title position

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have an AMChart which I've added a category title to but I can't get it to display properly and no matter what parameters I tweak, I can't get it to show at the right distance from the bottom of the chart area.

Here is a minimal JSFiddle showing the problem, can anyone make the category title render properly?  http://jsfiddle.net/MW4BU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by removing `&nbsp;` from your div

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks.  A rouge amp nbsp semicolon, who would have thought

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the chart margins manually? I haven't tested this yet, but it might solve your issue:

**Example code:**

```
  // autoMargins should be set to false in order chart to use custom margin values 
    chart.autoMargins = false;
    chart.marginTop = 60;
    chart.marginBottom = 60;
    chart.marginLeft = 30;
    chart.marginRight = 30;
```

Comment: I think this is the right kind of area, but obviously turning off auto margins stops it calculating the best width for the side margins.  Thanks for the pointer though

Comment: You may have already tried this, but Amcharts has a great free [support forum](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/) where the developer is usually very responsive to any questions. I would post your question there as well.